# Error in parsing StoryBoard in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I am developing an application in Xamarin.iOS. But after three days of work, Xamarin cannot render the Main.StoryBoard and gives the following error:

```
There was an error in Parsing the XML in this document
```

and a long list of logs.

Any idea how to revert to or something like this

Comment: Sounds like there has been a change in xml, possible a merge or somethign else casuing invalid XML. You can manually fix this or revert from your source control if you are using one. Can you post the error log or upload the storyboard to github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Xhulio ran into this before. Try opening it with Xcode first to see if it works. If not you can try opening the storyboard with an XML editor (I used Notepadd++ with an XML plugin), then identify and correct the invalid XML. If you are using source control you can try comparing your changes to identify the issue. Hope this helps.